# Code Shortening

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

this is my first question!

```
$champion1greenwards = 0;
$champion2greenwards = 0;
$champion3greenwards = 0;
$champion4greenwards = 0;
$champion5greenwards = 0;
$champion6greenwards = 0;
$champion7greenwards = 0;
$champion8greenwards = 0;
$champion9greenwards = 0;
$champion10greenwards = 0;


foreach($json as $arrays) {
      if (is_array($arrays)) {
        foreach($arrays as $arrayx) {
                foreach($arrayx as $arrayt) {
                        foreach($arrayt as $array) {

           if ($array['type'] == 'WARD_PLACED' &&  $array['wardType'] == 'SIGHT_WARD' && $array['creatorId'] == '1') {
            $champion1greenwards++;
          }
               if ($array['type'] == 'WARD_PLACED' &&  $array['wardType'] == 'SIGHT_WARD' && $array['creatorId'] == '2') {
            $champion2greenwards++;
          }
               if ($array['type'] == 'WARD_PLACED' &&  $array['wardType'] == 'SIGHT_WARD' && $array['creatorId'] == '3') {
            $champion3greenwards++;
          }
               if ($array['type'] == 'WARD_PLACED' &&  $array['wardType'] == 'SIGHT_WARD' && $array['creatorId'] == '4') {
            $champion4greenwards++;
          }
               if ($array['type'] == 'WARD_PLACED' &&  $array['wardType'] == 'SIGHT_WARD' && $array['creatorId'] == '5') {
            $champion5greenwards++;
          }
               if ($array['type'] == 'WARD_PLACED' &&  $array['wardType'] == 'SIGHT_WARD' && $array['creatorId'] == '6') {
            $champion6greenwards++;
          }
               if ($array['type'] == 'WARD_PLACED' &&  $array['wardType'] == 'SIGHT_WARD' && $array['creatorId'] == '7') {
            $champion7greenwards++;
          }
               if ($array['type'] == 'WARD_PLACED' &&  $array['wardType'] == 'SIGHT_WARD' && $array['creatorId'] == '8') {
            $champion8greenwards++;
          }
                   if ($array['type'] == 'WARD_PLACED' &&  $array['wardType'] == 'SIGHT_WARD' && $array['creatorId'] == '9') {
            $champion9greenwards++;
          }
                       if ($array['type'] == 'WARD_PLACED' &&  $array['wardType'] == 'SIGHT_WARD' && $array['creatorId'] == '10') {
            $champion10greenwards++;
          }


        }
                }
        }
      }
    }
$championgreenwards = array($champion1greenwards,$champion2greenwards,$champion3greenwards,$champion4greenwards,$champion5greenwards,$champion6greenwards,$champion7greenwards,$champion8greenwards,$champion9greenwards,$champion10greenwards);
```

Result  $championgreenwards array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 14
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 20
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 16
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 23
)
```

With this code I count how many times champion 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 placed wards in a map and then I make an array with the data. But the code is so long and I dont know how to shorten this code. I could not find a way to do it. So I came here.

Comment: Why do you use 10 variables and afterwards convert them to an array? Just use the array from the beginning

Comment: Can you post example of the `$json`?

Comment: @PetrHejda Its so huge. I cant post it to pastebin because filesize rule. Why you need it? It has a bunch of arrays that has [type] => WARD_PLACED and i count every players total wards. My code is working but too long.

Comment: This should be on CodeReview

Comment: @MacroMan Sorry for that im new to this site :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$greenwards = [];
foreach($json as $arrays) {
  if (is_array($arrays)) {
    foreach($arrays as $arrayx) {
      foreach($arrayx as $arrayt) {
        foreach($arrayt as $array) {
          if ($array['type'] == 'WARD_PLACED' &&  $array['wardType'] == 'SIGHT_WARD') {
            $greenwards[$array['creatorId']]++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much its working :=)

I changed greenwards array to default 10 "0" values. And  `$greenwards[$array['creatorId']]++;` changed to `$greenwards[$array['creatorId'] - 1]++;` so it become what i exactly want.

Comment: Its both working i marked yours because i did it from your answer. Made that little changes. Then i saw his answer.  :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$championgreenwards = array_fill(0, 10, 0);

foreach($json as $arrays) {
    if (!is_array($arrays)) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach($arrays as $arrayx) {
       foreach($arrayx as $arrayt) {
          foreach($arrayt as $array) {
              if ($array['type'] == 'WARD_PLACED' &&  $array['wardType'] == 'SIGHT_WARD') {
                  $championgreenwards[$array['creatorId']-1]++;
              }
          }
       }
    }
}

var_dump($championgreenwards);
```

Or using `array_walk_recursive`, like this:

```
array_walk_recursive($json, function ($array) use (&$championgreenwards) {
    if (!is_array($array) || !isset($array['type']) || !isset($array['wardType'])) {
        return;
    }

    if ($array['type'] == 'WARD_PLACED' &&  $array['wardType'] == 'SIGHT_WARD') {
        $championgreenwards[$array['creatorId']-1]++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for effort i already did it i can only tick 1 answer sry for that.